# Laravel - Intervention Image Caching Issue

Tags: laravel

I'm resizing images with code below:

```
Route::get('/public/{width}x{height}/{path}', function ($width, $height, $path) {
    // Load the original image
    $image = Image::make('blabla.com/'.$path);

    // Resize the image while maintaining the aspect ratio
    if ($width == 0) {
        $image->heighten($height);
    } elseif ($height == 0) {
        $image->widen($width);
    } else {
        $image->fit($width, $height);
    }

    // Return the resized image with appropriate headers
    return $image->response();
})->where('path', '.*');
```

But it doesnt cache anything. It make resize everytime i request it, so its a huge load for my server.

How can I cache images, if they are generated once? (They can be cached forever, if not error returns).

Whats the best way to handle it?
Should I do it on cloudflare side *.jpg, *.png always cache? Or whats best option?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to determine if caching by `cloudflare`, browser or code is the right option, as all have benefits and disadvantages. Most of the times i would argue, that setting it up in `cloudflare` is the most correct in terms of looking at it with the architecture in mind.

If you want to handle it in the code, `Laravel` has helpers for this.

```
return Cache::remember(
    $path, // the key to cache data by
    86400, // cache for a day, forever caching can be a problem as it takes storage space
    function () use () {
        return $this->yourCode(); // call your own code as it was before
    }
);
```

This solution will utilize the cache, as per default it is set to the file driver, so it will save it as a file. If you run `redis` or something more performance optimize, it will off course run better.